# Trying to reproduce a javascript b64_md5 function with PHP, but results differ

Tags: javascript, php, base64, md5

I am trying to tap into an existing web application that uses the b64_md5 js function to encrypt a password before sending it to the server for security purposes.  My script uses PHP and PHP Curl, but I can't seem to get the same result using php and the same inputs.

Here is the JS that generates the encrypted password using the following script:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/romeoh/3302246/raw/5fa924ca5ec39b0c3607441d0c077566f36005bc/md5.js

```
var PasswordMD5 = encodeURIComponent(b64_md5("Dn@v9Dr3HCBM0.95995490.9737542"));
```

That function returns:
HRQghiCMPfmGHJ67byxCjg==

I'm trying to match that result using PHP.  Here is what I've got, but it's not generating a matching result.

```
<?
$passwordMD5 = base64_encode(md5("Dn@v9Dr3HCBM0.95995490.9737542"));
echo $passwordMD5;
?>
```

That function returns:
MWQxNDIwODYyMDhjM2RmOTg2MWM5ZWJiNmYyYzQyOGU=

Are there any md5/encoding gurus out there that can help me figure this out?

Comment: Using [spark-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spark-md5) I get `1d142086208c3df9861c9ebb6f2c428e`, same for PHP's `md5("Dn@v9Dr3HCBM0.95995490.9737542")` If I do `btoa(SparkMD5.hash("Dn@v9Dr3HCBM0.95995490.9737542"))` in [JS](https://jsfiddle.net/pq7yjds9/) I get `MWQxNDIwODYyMDhjM2RmOTg2MWM5ZWJiNmYyYzQyOGU=`, exactly as from [PHP](https://ideone.com/kWCqAB).

Comment: My guess is that `HRQghiCMPfmGHJ67byxCjg==` is the base64 version of the binary string, while the longer M string is the base64 of the hex string.

Comment: Final note: afaik, hashing the password on the client is pointless. If nobody is listening in, you might as well send the actual password. *If* somebody is listening in, they now have the hash, and can use that to log in. Sure, they don't have the actual password, but (again afaik) hashing is primarily used to store passwords in a database, since the risk of that getting into the wrong hands is far greater.

Comment: Ding, ding, ding!  You nailed it.  I added a hextobin() around the MD5 function and it worked.  Thanks!